# Setting the minimum size of a html page

Tags: html, min, css

In HTML and CSS, I have tried to many methods but none seem to work. I need to set the minimum width and height of my page so that the browser window cannot be resized below a certain pixel range. For instance, the window can be resized equal to or greater that 500 x 700 px, but not below. I have tried the min-height and min-width properties but didn't work. maybe i am not using them correctly.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: It's not possible. You can set min-width and min-height to ensure a minimum content size, but the browser window is part of the OS, which leaves it out of your control.

Comment: Yes. Like @JorisLindhout said you cannot restrict window/browser resize.